# Characterizing the family of Borel subsets of a subspace

Tags: general-topology

Given any topological space $X$, let $\mathcal{B}(X)$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of $X$.

> Let $X$ be a topological space and let $Y\subset X$ be given the relative topology. Then $\mathcal{B}(Y) =\mathcal{B}(X)\cap Y$, where $\mathcal{B}(X)\cap Y$ denotes $\lbrace B\cap Y : B\in \mathcal{B}(X)\rbrace$.

This question seems very simple, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, observe that $B(X)\cap Y$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$. It is also clear that it contains all (relatively) open subsets of $Y$, so $B(Y)\subset B(X)\cap Y$.

Conversely, consider the collection of sets $\mathcal M=\{ E\subset X: E\cap Y\in B(Y)\}$. Again, it's straightforward to check that this is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. Moreover, all open (in $X$) sets are in $\mathcal M$, so $B(X)\subset\mathcal M$ and hence also $B(X)\cap Y\subset\mathcal M\cap Y = B(Y)$.